# How to add a widget to a Class using outside class function?

Tags: python, kivy

Super new to Kivy. Trying to add a label to the the gridlayout after the button is clicked, using outside method exclusively. No errors, just nothing shows up. Here's my code. Please help.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import datetime

a="" 

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.submit=Button(text="submit" , font_size=40)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)
        self.submit.bind(on_press= ff)
        self.txt=TextInput(multiline=True)
        self.txt.bind(text = self.on_text)
        self.add_widget(self.txt)
        
    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        global a
        a=value

    def func(self, instance):
        self.add_widget(Label(text=a)) 


def ff(instance):        
    MyGrid().add_widget(Label(text="something"))     
    

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in `ff` function you create a new instance of `MyGrid()` instead of using the one you already have. To fix it, in the `app.build()` method change what you have for:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = root = MyGrid()
        return root
```

This way you're able to reference the root widget. Then in your `ff` function:

```
def ff(instance):
    App.get_running_app().root.add_widget(Label(text="something"))
```

Comment: @Manana Glad to hear that. If was helpful you can mark it as "accepted answer"